# Mapping a NumPy array in place but Map function depends on x,y position in array

Tags: function, numpy, position, mapping, element

I found several answers on mapping numpy array in place but I have that problem, that my mapping functions needs as an input it's element position. For this, i didnt find answer.

Example: I am doing kind of bilinear interpolation with 4 corners(quadrangle, not square) and I would like to map whole array on a function similar to this:

```
def calculate_weight(corner_positions,x,y):
    #corner_position - list of corner positions
    #x,y is actual element position of an array
    #distance() - function to calculate euclid distance
    return np.mean([distance(v,(x,y)) for v in corner_positions])

corner_positions = [[0,0],[10,10],[0,10],[10,0]]
numpy_array = np.zeros(shape=[10,10])
numpy_array[each_element] = calculate_weight(corner_positions,elements_row, element_column)
```

so in this sample mapping function, I would like to assign to each element an **average** without using loop over rows and columns.

As I said, I found several answers on StackOverflow on mapping over numpy arrays, but I didnt find one, where I can use elements position in the array as an argument.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your argument `corner_positions` is an element of the matrix?

Comment: [extract all vertical slices from numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51332319/extract-all-vertical-slices-from-numpy-array) shows how to get element indices along with values.

Comment: hpaulj, I dont have problem with extracting this information. My problem is that I want to map all elements with a function on few lines of code without use of iteration

Comment: What is `distance`?

Comment: hpaulj, Does it matter? Its in comment but it doesnt matter at all. The code is just example